# Characterization of continuous one-parameter groups of linear operators on finite-dimensional spaces

Tags: matrices, reference-request, matrix-calculus, semigroup-of-operators

I'm looking for a nice textbook that proves this elementary result:

**Theorem.**  Suppose $V$ is a finite-dimensional real or complex vector space, and suppose that $\{U(t)\}_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ is a **continuous 1-parameter group** of linear operators on $V$, meaning

- $U(t) : V \to V$ is a linear operator for each $t \in \mathbb{R}$;
- $U(t)$ depends continuously on $t$ (in the usual topology on the space of linear operators from $V$ to itself);
- $U(0) = 1_V$;
- $U(s+t) = U(s) U(t)$ for all $s, t \in \mathbb{R}$.

Then there exists a unique linear operator $H : V \to V$ such that $U(t) = \exp(tH)$.  Conversely, for any linear operator $H : V \to V$, if $U(t) = \exp(tH)$ then $\{U(t)\}_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ is a continuous 1-parameter group of linear operators on $V$.

**I'd really like a reference to a proof that only does the finite-dimensional case—and please give me the theorem number, since I need this for a paper I'm writing.  The referee is demanding a reference!**

I find it sad that no reference to a proof of this result is given in the Wikipedia articles ["Matrix exponential"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential) and ["One-parameter group"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-parameter_group).

I would accept a proof of the more general result where $V$ is a Banach space and $\{U(t)\}_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ is a 1-parameter group of bounded linear operators that's continuous in the norm topology.  The proof is exactly the same!  But I'd rather not bring in these extra concepts.

I really *don't* want a theorem that considers the case where $V$ is infinite-dimensional and $\{U(t)\}_{t \in \mathbb{R}}$ is only continuous in the strong topology.  This is distractingly technical for what I need!

Answer (score 2):

This result is proved in Chapter 1 (Linear Dynamical Systems), Section 2 (Finite-Dimensional Systems: Matrix Semigroups), of [Engel's book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=q0YMCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=One-Parameter+Semigroups+for+Linear+Evolution+Equations&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiC-OThvM_TAhVKHJAKHWi2AwcQ6AEIIjAA#v=onepage&q=One-Parameter%20Semigroups%20for%20Linear%20Evolution%20Equations&f=false) (One-Parameter Semigroups for Linear Evolution Equations).

After Theorem 2.9 (p. 11) we read

> With this theorem we have characterized all continuous one-parameter groups on $\mathbb C^n$ as matrix-valued exponential functions

which is exactly what you want (for the complex case).

(Since the context of the book is primarily semigroups, the first paragraph in page 9 is relevant.)

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I want.  In fact it's even better than what I asked for, because it handles the case of continuous one-parameter _semigroups_ of operators on a finite-dimensional vector space, which is actually what I'm concerned with.  (I had been prepared to show any such thing is actually a continuous one-parameter group.)

Answer (score -1):

Take your favorite book on Lie groups, a morphism $f:G\rightarrow H$ between Lie groups induces a morphism $Lie(f):Lie(G)\rightarrow Lie(H)$ between their Lie algebra which commutes with the exponential. Here take $G=\mathbb{R}$ and $H=Gl(n,\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: I want a proof that does not require the reader to know Lie theory.  There's a simple direct proof.  It's interesting to think about whether this simple direct proof is easier, or harder, than the proof that a continuous homomorphism between Lie groups is automatically differentiable and gives a morphism of Lie algebras that commutes with the exponential.